# multi-term: after ssh to a remote server, the prompt messed up

Tags: term, multi-term

The expected prompt is /home/oracle, but it's something like \342\236\234. What need to do to get it show the right folder name?
[image]

Comment: What does "echo $PS1" (or "echo $PS1 | od -x" if the first command is unreadable) output?

Comment: It's ${ret_status} %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)
I am using zsh on the ssh server.